# QString in initializer list causes access violation. What goes wrong here?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, access-violation, initializer-list

I encountered an access-violation when using a QString in a initializer-list that I do not understand.

Here is a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

```
// file ClassA.h
#pragma once
#include <QString>

struct Parameter
{
    QString stringPar;
};

class ClassA
{
     QString m_string1;

public:
    void function(Parameter pars);
};
```

Implementation of ClassA...

```
// file ClassA.cpp
#include "ClassA.h"

void ClassA::function(Parameter pars)
{
    m_string1 = pars.stringPar;   // last line called in my code when the crash happens
}
```

and main.cpp

```
// file main.cpp
#include "ClassA.h"

int main()
{
    ClassA classA;

    classA.function({ QString("jkjsdghdkjhgdjufgskhdbfgskzh") });

    // when using this code the problem does not occur
    //Parameter par = { QString("jkjsdghdkjhgdjufgskhdbfgskzh") };
    //classA.function(par);

    return 0;
}
```

The call stack at the time of the violation:

```
Qt5Cored.dll!QGenericAtomicOps<QAtomicOpsBySize<4> >::load<long>(const long & _q_value) Line 96
Qt5Cored.dll!QBasicAtomicInteger<int>::load() Line 142
Qt5Cored.dll!QtPrivate::RefCount::ref() Line 57
Qt5Cored.dll!QString::operator=(const QString & other) Line 1355
EducationalCode.exe!ClassA::function(Parameter pars) Line 6
EducationalCode.exe!main() Line 8
```

Something seems to go wrong with the copy assignment in ClassA::function() but I am not sure what it is. 
When I change the signature of function to

```
function(const Parameter& pars);
```

it does not crash either.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Doesn't look like it should crash...and it didn't crash on me (Qt5.3, gcc4.8.2, kubuntu 32-bit).  What compiler, version of Qt, OS, etc.?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit, Visual Studio 2013 with Update 2, Qt 5.1.1

Comment: If you change `QString` to `std::string` does it work?

Comment: MSVC [has a known](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/804731) [double-destruction bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807610) in its handling of initializer lists.

Comment: Changing the QString into std:string causes causes the program to freeze in debug mode when returning from ClassA::function(). In release mode it crashes. So I guess the answer is that from Igor Tandetnik, and it just a bug on the msvc side and not illegeal c++ on my side.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a copy constructor:

```
struct Parameter
{
    QString stringPar;
    Parameter& Parameter(const Parameter& rhs)
    {
        if((void*)this == (void*)&rhs)
        {
            return *this;
        }
        this->stringPar = rhs.stringPar;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

A temp Parameter instance is created when you call ClassA::function() because of C++ passing arguments by value;
Something like this:

```
void ClassA::function(Parameter pars = QString("jkjsdghdkjhgdjufgskhdbfgskzh"))
{
    m_string1 = pars.stringPar;   // last line called in my code when the crash happens
}
```

If you don't write a copy constructor, compiler will synthesize a default copy constructor like this:

```
    Parameter& Parameter(const Parameter& rhs)
    {
        memcpy(this, &rhs, sizeof(Parameter));
        return *this;
    }
```

I guess QString has pointer members, assuming it's name is ptr.
then pars.stringPar.ptr and QString("jkjsdghdkjhgdjufgskhdbfgskzh").stringPar.ptr will point to the same memory address.

Call function like this:

```
 classA.function({ QString("jkjsdghdkjhgdjufgskhdbfgskzh") });
```

{ QString("jkjsdghdkjhgdjufgskhdbfgskzh") } object destroy before  classA.function() return,
then memory pointed by {QString("jkjsdghdkjhgdjufgskhdbfgskzh")}.stringPar.ptr is freed,
and pars.stringPar.ptr point to invalid memory.

```
// when using this code the problem does not occur
//Parameter par1 = { QString("jkjsdghdkjhgdjufgskhdbfgskzh") };
//classA.function(par1)
//par1 destroy when main() function return, thus classA.function() does not crash.
```

See << Effective C++  >>
Item 11:  Declare a copy constructor and an assignment operator for classes with dynamically allocated memory. 
Effective C++, 2E 
http://debian.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/~mrpaff/Effective%20C++/EC/EI11_FR.HTM

Comment: QString has a copy-constructor and and asignment operator. I mentioned in the comments that the problem can be reproduced by using std::string instead of QString. So I do not really see why i would need to write my own copy constructor for the Parameter struct as the default one should be ok.

"{ QString("jkjsdghdkjhgdjufgskhdbfgskzh") } object destroy before classA.function() return,...". I thought that unnamed variables in function arguments are guaranteed to live until the function returns, but maybe I was wrong.